# Do IAsyncRequests have to be register in DI

Tags: c#, unity-container, mediatr

Using MediatR,

do `IAsyncRequest<T>` have to be registered in the container.

I've got `Unity` auto registering everything and quite rightly it's complaining that I have multiple bindings against `IAsyncRequest<bool>`.

So I figure I have two options, don't register `IAsyncRequest<T>` or don't auto register `IAsyncRequest<T>`, give them named registrations.

I think doing the former is the easiest, and I was just wondering if there was any special reason to have the `IAsyncRequest` registered to their concrete impls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they do not. Only handlers need to be registered. Check out the GitHub repo for a working example of Unity registration.

Comment: Yeah that's where I got my code from, I got unity ignoring them know. cheers

Comment: Can you please provide a working sample with Unity and WebAPI, it would be great help.